# R binomial test preferences, data frame

Tags: r

This is a Coursera course, which expects us to do R programming without any previous experience with R, and I'm really trying hard to understand, but have no clue. I even checked basic R tutorials, but still no idea.

We have a csv file, content:

- Subjects: 30
- Disability: 0, 1
- Preference: trackball, touchpad

For people without disabilities, perform a binomial test to see whether their preference for touchpads differed significantly from chance. To the nearest ten-thousandth (four digits), what is the p-value? Hint: Run a binomial test comparing the sum of rows of people without disabilities who prefer the touchpad, against the number of all rows of people without disabilities. With two possible preferences, touchpad and trackball, the chance probability would be 1/2. Do not correct for multiple comparisons; consider this a single test on a subset of the data.

The solution supposed to be:

- First, gain intuition by plotting the preferences of people without disabilities:

  ```
  plot(df[df$Disability == "0",]$Pref)
  ```
- Second, test the preference for touchpads vs. trackballs against chance, which would be no preference:

  ```
  binom.test(sum(df[df$Disability == "0",]$Pref == "touchpad"), 
             nrow(df[df$Disability == "0",]), p=1/2)
  plot(df[df$Disability == "0",]$Pref)
  ```

I understand, that this supposed to gives us a visual representation of Disability=0's preferences, but there is an error with the dfs and I don't know how to correct it. Can someone help please?

Comment: It'd be better if you provided the data you are working with, so we can reproduce your code. Try `dput`, or maybe upload this csv somewhere and post a link.

Comment: Please also add the error message in the question.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!  I just figured out I need to replace "df" with the built xtab's name. Files:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/rd796wor7by5uky/DesignExperiments_R.Rproj?dl=0     https://www.dropbox.com/s/cig2u4d5vpkjma1/deviceprefs.csv?dl=0

Comment: @testimo you can add it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated a random data-set with the given characteristics and everything works just fine :

```
df <- data.frame(Subject = c("Sub1", "Sub2", "Sub3", "Sub4", "Sub5", "Sub6", "Sub7", "Sub8", "Sub9", "Sub10", "Sub11", "Sub12", "Sub13", "Sub14", "Sub15", "Sub16", "Sub17", "Sub18", "Sub19", "Sub20", "Sub21", "Sub22",     "Sub23", "Sub24", "Sub25", "Sub26", "Sub27", "Sub28", "Sub29", "Sub30"),
                 Disability = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0"),
                 Pref = c("touchpad", "touchpad", "touchpad", "trackball", "trackball", "trackball", "trackball", "trackball", "trackball", "trackball", "trackball", "trackball", "touchpad", "trackball", "trackball", "touchpad", "touchpad", "trackball", "touchpad", "trackball", "touchpad", "touchpad", "trackball", "touchpad", "touchpad", "touchpad", "touchpad", "touchpad", "trackball", "trackball"))
```

The result of the given command is the following

```
binom.test(sum(df[df$Disability == "0",]$Pref == "touchpad"), 
           nrow(df[df$Disability == "0",]), p=1/2)

    Exact binomial test

data:  sum(df[df$Disability == "0", ]$Pref == "touchpad") and nrow(df[df$Disability == "0", ])
number of successes = 8, number of trials = 18, p-value = 0.8145
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2153015 0.6924283
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.4444444
```

---

EDIT

In order to apply the same test to the real data (link to the file given in a comment), the first step should be replaced by a command reading the value stored in the *actual* data-frame :

```
df <- read.csv("deviceprefs-1.csv")
```

Again, the given command to perform the binomial test works just fine with the real data-set.

Comment: Thank you for trying @vincent-guillemot  I gave the answer p-value = 0.8145 and the test said it is incorrect.

Comment: i think you misunderstood my answer: when I said "simulated", it means I randomly generated some data, so the p-value does not correspond to your data.